# How can I get more detail about an error on a Data-hub job that's getting an Invalid Date error?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

When I run a step in a Data-Hub 5.0 flow, I'm getting an "Invalid Date" error.  The data I'm ingesting is from a csv file.  It's being put into a database where all the fields are defined as strings.  I am not sure where to look to get a better breakdown of the error.   Here is a screen shot:
[image: Data-hub Jobs status screen]

Comment: How are you loading the data? Using MLCP?

Comment: Yes I'm using the Data-Hub local web interface.  It uses MLCP.  At least that is what I'm assuming.

Comment: It uses the localhost site set up by:  java -jar marklogic-datahub-5.2.0.war

Comment: Apparently there are issues with the MLCP import not recording an end time (though I can't find an issue to reference). But that isn't necessarily an error, as it is running step 3, but is confusing/concerning not to have the end date.